# Method or Procedure to create Subscriptions with parameters using a Report

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

I have some dashboards with Reporting Services and SharePoint, some need parameters some of them do not need parameters. I want to create something standard(I've think in a standard report) that receives all the possible parameters of the dashboards.

My idea: In my report will exist a button with the name Suscribe, this button displays a report or form that will receive all the important parameters directly from the report that called it, in this new report or form the user will choose the periodicity, write his mail and/or a CC.

I've seen some examples, but this examples need to create a subscription before hand, and I have more than 100 reports and differents users can create differents subscriptions.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Development/datadrivensubscriptions/2432/
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Development/2824/

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sql Server Enterprise Edition then you have support for data driven subscriptions in which case you can define sp's or a query that returns email addresses for the given report. If you are not using EE the data driven subscriptions are not supported:(